# PHP: How to get the page name of an url

Tags: php

I need to get the page name of an URL in PHP.

This is the url:

```
$url = 'product-details.php?descr=round-small-table&product=table-brwonk&id=35&lang=en;
```

How can I extract **product-details.php** from the url above?

Comment: ...or parse_url() ;)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the problem is.

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: \__FILE__ can maybe help you ;) or `split('?')[0]`

Comment: `parse_url, substr strpos, explode, pregmatch` Many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
?>
```

Parse_url is what you're searching for ! The scheme here would be "PHP_URL_PATH" I guess

---

Some doc : http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: or just: `var_dump( parse_url( $url )["path"]  );` ;), at least with OPs example

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the page name using  following script: $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$page = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);